# if $(-1)$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$, then it is not an eigenvalue of $A(B^{-1})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be invertible matrices of order $n\times n$ over $\mathbb C$. It is easy to prove that if $(-1)$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $B$, then it is **not** an eigenvalue of $B^{-1}$. Under what conditions, it is true that if $(-1)$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $AB$, then it is **not** an eigenvalue of $A(B^{-1})$ ?

Comment: $A(B^{-1})$ or $(AB)^{-1}$?

Comment: the first one, namely, $A(B^{-1})$

Comment: Thank Andreas, but I don't see how?

Comment: @Andreas How do you prove it if $A$ and $B$ commute?

Comment: @Andreas That isn't true. Consider $A=i$ and $B=-i$ for instance. In this case $AB=1$ but $AB^{-1}=-1$.

Comment: @user1551 Ah, you are right, thanks! I just wanted to type up a small proof, but I see that it is wrong now. xD

Comment: $A=2$, $B = -2$

Comment: It is clear that it is not true for every A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sufficient conditions:

1. $B=B^{-1}$, for the trivial reason;
2. $A$ is Hermitian and $B$ is unitary, so that $BA=(AB^{-1})^\ast$ (recall that for any two square matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same spectrum);
3. $A$ is complex symmetric and $B$ is complex orthogonal, so that $BA=(AB^{-1})^T$;
4. $A\overline{A}=I$ and $B$ is real, so that $BA=\left(\overline{AB^{-1}}\right)^{-1}$.

Note that we may interchange the roles of $A$ and $B$ in each of the above cases, because $AB$ has the same spectrum as $BA$, and $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$ iff $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $BA^{-1}=(AB^{-1})^{-1}$.